# Why does my query work with the RIGHT() and LEFT() functions, but not with the LIKE predicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select rows in which a column value DOES NOT START or END with a vowel. However, if I try to do so by using the `LIKE` predicate to determine the condition in the `WHERE` clause, I get a runtime error.

```
select distinct COLUMN
from TABLE
where COLUMN not like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

If I use the RIGHT and LEFT functions to do so, my query works properly.

````
select distinct COLUMN
from TABLE where (left(COLUMN, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
and right(COLUMN, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u'))```
````

That's a pretty long and redundant alternative, though. I would like to understand why the first one doesn't work or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent comparison for:

```
COLUMN not like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

uses `or`, not `and`:

```
where left(COLUMN, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') or
      right(COLUMN, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

or equivalently:

```
where not (left(COLUMN, 1) in ('a','e','i','o','u') and
           right(COLUMN, 1) in ('a','e','i','o','u')
          )
```

(because "not (a and b)" is the same -- logically -- as "not a or not b).

Consider the fair city of `'Miami'`.  It matches the `not like` because it does not begin and end with a vowel.  It just has to fail *one* of the comparisons.

Comment: Although I realize now my question was probably a little ambiguous, I think I understand the issue with my query a little better.
I would like my 'not like' condition to bring me the same rows that a "not a and not b" condition would, which would rule out 'Miami' as a result.

Comment: boolean trap every where. boolean trap every where.

Comment: @SamaraGama you can't do what you want to do using `like` because like is `and` and you need `or` (and SQL Server has not regex support).